# API design - passing same request parameter multiple times in a request

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I am designing an API, and was wondering what the best practice is for handling request that may contain the same request parameter multiple times. (e.g. /resource?paramA=XYZ&paramA=ABC&paramB=DEF)  Should the values be taken as a single list, or if this should not be a valid request, or the last one wins, etc?  Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer depends on context heavily.

For example, if a user wants to GET:

```
/photo?member=John&member=Alice
```

it might be considered as a valid request, i.e. the user tries to get a group photo with John and Alice.

But if a user wants to GET:

```
/photo?type=monochrome&type=mulitcolor
```

it should be considered as an invalid request, because a photo can't be monochrome and multicolor at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the style you describe is used to submit multiple values under the same query parameter, which I think you're describing as "a single list". I don't see why you wouldn't accept it as-is. If multiple values aren't allowed for that query parameter, your API should response with a 4xx indicating the problem.